# button.configure() command not running inside while loop in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, while-loop

I am trying to configure the button based on the value of `turn` which is determined by the while loop which is determined by the value of `game_over`

The while loop is interfering with the main loop of tkinter. I can't seem to figure out a way around this.

This is the code.

```
from tkinter import *
connect = Toplevel()

col1 = Button(connect, width=10, height=4, text=" ")
col1.grid(row=0, column=1)

game_over = False
turn = 0

while not game_over:
    if turn == 0:
        col1.configure(bg="#FE6869")
        x=input("Enter something")
        if x=="yes":
            game_over=True
        else:
            continue   
    else:       
        col1.configure(bg="#FFFC82")
        x=input("Enter something")
        if x=="no":
            game_over=True
        else:
            continue
    turn += 1
    turn = turn % 2

connect.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's running, but you're preventing `mainloop` from being able to update the display.

Answer (score 5):

First, I would not recommend to use potentially infinite while loops. Second you should check how to create a tkinter application, first create your root window before you create any TopLevel widget. Next, buttons can execute functions specified as command. Lastly, if you work with a GUI based approach, you can get the user input as well from the GUI.
I made an example application from your code. I highly recommend you to watch some tutorials on tkinter before continuing.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog as sd


def start():
    global turn
    global game_over

    if not game_over:
        if turn == 0:
            col1.configure(bg="#FE6869")
            x=sd.askstring('User Input', 'Enter something')
            if x=="yes":
                game_over=True
                end = tk.Label(connect, text='GAME OVER')
                end.grid(row=1, column=0)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            col1.configure(bg="#FFFC82")
            x=sd.askstring('User Input', "Enter something")
            if x=="no":
                game_over=True
                end = tk.Label(connect, text='GAME OVER')
                end.grid(row=1, column=0)
            else:
                pass
        turn += 1
        turn = turn % 2


connect = tk.Tk()

turn = 0
game_over = False

col1 = tk.Button(connect, width=10, height=4, text=" ", command=start)
col1.grid(row=0, column=0)

connect.mainloop()
```